# SQL: search space seperated word in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column contains space seperated words:

```
|         tags           |
--------------------------
| python javascript java |
```

Now I'd like to select rows that have a certain word.

`select * from table where [`'java'`in tags]`

note that when I select with `java`, rows contain only `javascript` should not be selected, which means its has to be word level match.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FIND_IN_SET` to get the correct rows. Since it uses comma separators, you'll need to replace the spaces with commas to get the correct result;

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('java', REPLACE(tags, ' ', ',')) > 0
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/542cef/1).

That said, a query using the table format you're displaying will *not be able to use indexes* and will be quite slow when the amount of data grows. You'll be *much* better off using a row per tag instead so that you can use a simple equals match. That way indexes will be used and you'll get quite a performance boost.

[A quick sample of that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c82f/1).

Answer (score 0):

i initially thought of using FIND_IN_SET, but simple LIKE should give what you are expecting.

```
select * from tableA where tags LIKE '%java%'
```

Comment: this will select javascript I think